# Exportar Kendo Grid para PDF

Tags: pdf, kendo-ui

Tenho uma função que exporta para Excel e preciso de outra que exporte para PDF.  A função deverá exportar os dados de uma Kendo Grid.

```
function ExportarParaExcel(grid) {
   grid = grid == undefined ? "#grid" : grid;
   var grd = $(grid).data("kendoGrid");
   grd.bind("excelExport", function (e) {
       var rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;
       for (var ri = 0; ri < rows.length; ri++) {
           var row = rows[ri];
           var dd = '';
           if (row.type == "group-header" || row.type == "header" || row.type == "group-footer" || row.type == "footer") {
               for (var ci = 0; ci < row.cells.length; ci++) {
                   var cell = row.cells[ci];
                   if (cell.value) {
                       cell.value = ajustaAcentosXLS(cell.value);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   });
   grd.saveAsExcel();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrado a solução na [pergunta do Stack Overflow (Inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438280/kendo-ui-export-grid-to-pdf-without-pages-chunks). Ela soluciona o problema de exportação, mas identifiquei que para o meu caso, é melhor exportar somente para Excel.